# Prove $\int $ $(1/x)$ dx = $ln|x| + c$.

Tags: calculus, integration

Note the domain we are working with is $x$ is all real numbers except $0$.

My solution:

Separate the question into two cases.

(1) Prove that the left-side and the right-side of the equation are equal when $x < 0$

(2) Prove that the left-side and the right-side of the equation are equal when $x > 0$

(1) ($x < 0$) Implies:

$ln|x| = ln(-x)$ and that $1/x = (-1/x)$

$\int $ $(1/-x)$ dx = $ln(-x) + c$

Differentiate both sides of the equation..

Left-side: $-1/x$

Right-Side: $(1/x)*-1 = (-1/x)$

Since the left-side = the right side, the equation holds true for this half of the domain.

We take the same approach for when $x > 0$ and come to the conclusion that the equation holds true for x on the entire domain (all real numbers except 0) and QED.

Is this solution correct? If not, can someone highlight whether it is my approach or any particular operation I am carrying out that is the problem.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You're almost correct. You have one main mistake: the fact that $x<0$ does not mean that $1/x$ is $-1/x$. It stays $1/x$. The only place you get a minus sign is in the absolute value. So for $x<0$ you have

$$\frac{d}{dx} \ln(-x) = \frac{1}{-x} \cdot (-1) = \frac{1}{x}$$

which is what you wanted to prove.